# How do I convert and find the sum of a string with multiple numbers?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project where I have to find the total of a series of number in a string from a text file. I've created code where I can generally call a function to convert certain lines, but it only does so for the first number.

How can I modify my code so that I can add all of the numbers in the string, rather than just the first?

The line in the text is:

34.4 5416.9 1541.9 154.7 816.98

My code is as follows:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include<string>
   #include<fstream>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   using namespace std;

   string GetTotal ()
   {
      string total;
      ifstream login("textfile.txt");
      for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) // line 6 is where the numbers I need to add are
      { 
         getline(login, total);
      }

   return total;
   }

   int main ()
   {
   string total = GetTotal ();
   double data;
   data = atof(total.c_str()); //convert to double
   cout << data;

   return 0;
   }
```

The output comes out as 34.4.

To reiterate my question, what steps should I take so that I can add the numbers in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
istringstream ss(total);
vector<double> numbers;
double x;
while (ss >> x)
{
    numbers.push_back(x);
}
```

Now you have a vector of all the numbers. The rest should be easy!

Comment: @Arun Wouldn't it be `double sumResult = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0);`

Comment: I think you meant `istringstream` instead of `ostringstream`.

Comment: I haven't really learned about vectors yet so I'm not sure how to utilize this.

Comment: @Titanguy654 You can access them like an array. `numbers[4]` etc. Vectors are one of the most useful classes in C++, definitely worth the time to learn them.

Answer (score 0):

The current code is just returning the 1st element of the input stream, namely 34.4. That is because `atof()` consumed the string up to the first blank.

Consider @Neil's suggestion for the solution.